# Poner imagen desde Base de Datos en Marcador

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps

Tengo una base de datos en donde almaceno la ruta de imágenes las cuales están en una carpeta, quiero traer la imagen usando PHP para después ponerla en un marker, el código que tengo para hacer esto es el siguiente: 
ese codigo lo saque de https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fetch-image-from-a-MySQL-database-in-PHP
pero aun no se puedo ver las imagenes, como puedo hacer esto, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

PHP para guardar imagenes en CARPETA:

```
// Import db file.
require_once 'dbDetails.php';

// Upload folder.
$upload_path = 'uploads/';

// Get the server ip.
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// Create upload url.
$upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/userapp/' . $upload_path;

//response array 
$response = array();
```

PHP para obtener foto:

```
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "123", "rta" ) or die("Could not connect: " .mysqli_error($conn) );
$getImage=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT url FROM ts") or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($conn));
$path=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getImage) or die("Could not fetch array : " .mysqli_error($conn));

?>

<html>
<head><title>Fetch image form mysql</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="<?php echo 'uploads/'.$path['http:// .$server_ip . 
'/rta/' .$upload_path'];?>" />


<img src="<?php echo $path['image'];?>" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Segpun tu SELECT esto debería de ser url y no image: <img src="<?php echo $path['url'];?>" />

Comment: Lo acabo de cambiar y aun así no logro ver mis imágenes @CamiloVasquez tengo duda en como consultar o hacer referencia a la tabla por la forma de almacenar las fotos, acabo de editar el post